# Qt Connecting SIGNAL and SLOT in object member of MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a class MyClass with:

```
  - private: 
      pushButton *button;
      void connectSignalAndSlot();
  - private slot: 
      void buttonAction();
```

I want to connect these in MyClass using connectSignalAndSlot(), like so:

```
  void MyClass::connectSignalAndSlot()
  {
    QObject::connect(button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(buttonAction()));
  }
```

This gives me an error of

```
no matching function for call to 'QObject::connect(QPushButton*&, const char*, MyClass* const, const char*)';
```

If I inherit QObject with MyClass, the program compiles and starts, but then I get the following issues displayed in my Application Output pane:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::buttonAction() in ..\MyProject\myclass.cpp:48
```

Do I have to make the button and slot public and use them in the MainWindow class only?  Is there no way to keep this at the MyClass level?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have `MyClass` inherit from `QObject` AND add `Q_OBJECT` macro in your `MyClass` definition (header file) to have slots/signals work.

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
     ....
};
```

Comment: This is allowing it to run without those errors in the application output.  Thanks!  I'm doing this on two classes used in my project.  One works, and the other is giving a "QObject::QObject(constQObject&) is private" error.  I'm researching it now.

Comment: Found the issue.  A class that inherits QObject should not have the copy constructor called.  I changed the objects to pointers and problem is solved.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting `QObject` is the right way, but your still missing [Qt-Meta Object](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/moc.html) Code. Your header-file for your class should look like this:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    // your methods, variables, slots and signals
}

#endif
```

Don't forget to create the [moc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/moc.html) file, the easiest way is to use `qmake` or the `QtCreator` IDE.